# Why does this work when it looks like it's missing some return calls (DFS)?

Tags: depth-first-search

```
def dfs(s,d):
  def dfs_helper(s,d):
    if s==d:
      return True
    if s in visited:
      return False
    visited.add(s)
    for c in graph[s]:
      dfs_helper(c,d)
    return False
  visited = set()
  return dfs_helper(s,d)
```

I'm not sure why the above code is correct. I saw this in a paper but shouldn't it say `return dfs_helper(c,d)` instead of just `dfs_helper(c,d)` when looping through all the neighbors? Otherwise, how do we return anything all the way up since I thought returns only take you one level up to the immediate caller.

I.e. if we have a graph with edges (A,B), (A,C), and (C,D), I get why the `dfs_helper(D,D)` returns True, but when we run `dfs_helper(C,D)`, we just run `dfs_helper(D,D)` but we aren't RETURNING `dfs_helper(D,D)` so True does not get passed back up. Shouldn't that be the case? And if not, why is that so?

Comment: isFound = dfs_helper(c,d)  if(isFound == true) return true;  In case isFound is false then the for loop needs to continue so it should not return

Comment: But how does it ensure we return something even at the very beginning?

Comment: i didn't understand your question

Comment: the code I suggested is inside the for-loop, in case of true value return true else in case of false keep on continuing with further iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. It turns out I was on the right track.

I needed to change from

```
for c in graph[s]:
  dfs_helper(c,d)
```

to

```
for c in graph[s]:
  if dfs_helper(c,d): return True
```